# How to create a panel that opens from the right when a collapsed Navbar icon is clicked?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been trying to replicate a few designs from already existing websites. How do I implement a panel that opens from the right when a collapsed Navbar is clicked ?

This is what I'm trying to acheive.
[Target Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACfDO.png)

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I've tried a lot, messing with the alignment and padding but did not get a way to implement this. Do note that I don't need a right panel when the navbar is not collapsed (smaller viewports). Any suggestions ?

This is my current HTML code for the navbar

```
<nav class="navscroll navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-transparent navbar-dark fixed-top wow">

  <a class="navbar-brand d-sm-none d-md-block d-none d-sm-block" href="#">
    <img src="img/vamoslogo2.png" width="170" height=auto alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto hidden-sm-up float-xs-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">Blog </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I tried adding another class (.sidenav) so it becomes

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse sidenav" id="navbarCollapse">
```

And gave .sidenav the following CSS

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

As suggested by a post on w3schools. However, on doing this, all my navbar elements are not visible and my collapsed navbar does not work.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Can you post the code that you have tried? [mcve]

Comment: @imvain2 : My bad, I've added everything that I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the collapsed navbar is clicked, Bootstrap will probably change some classnames on the navbar element. Check this out in the inspector. Try to understand what happens and then write css that overrules what bootstrap does.
I'm don't know which classes bootstrap adds, but let's assume it adds a class 'collapsed', then you could write something like this and add your transition and other styling.

```
.sidenav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
.collapsed .sidenav {
    left:100vw;
    right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Great ! I'm able to move it to the right side. Not able to remove the custom bootstrap drop down animation though. I shall keep trying to find a fix.

Comment: Check in the inspector what's happening, then overwrite bootstraps' styling with stronger selectors. Please accept my answer if it's working.